# How to make the Residuals vs leverage plot that R produces when using plot(lmmodel)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I want to reproduce the 4th plot that R makes when you type:

```
plot(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars))
```

I find this plot useful for inspecting influential data points but even more I just want to know how to do that with ggplot. What I did was this:

- Make a subset of the data points that have high influence.
- Add an extra geom for these points.
- Added dashed horizontal line for residuals more than 3SD away + dashed vline for leverage greater than 2* the mean leverage (both is not in the plot I try to reproduce and I maybe take it out later again).

What I miss compared to the plot from R is:

- How do I plot Cook's distance cutoff line (like the line R makes)?
- How can I plot the rownumber (here the carnames)?

My code below:

```
mtcars$cooks.distance <- cooks.distance(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars))
mtcars$leverage <- hatvalues(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars))
mtcars$residuals.standard <- rstandard(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars))

influence <- mtcars[(mtcars$cooks.distance>0.05 & mtcars$leverage > 2*mean(mtcars$leverage)),]
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = leverage, y = residuals.standard)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2* mean(mtcars$leverage), linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(data = influence, aes(x = leverage, y = residuals.standard), color = 'orange')
```

Comment: When I type in R `fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data)`, I get `
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  'data' argument is of the wrong type`. what is your data? Can you use some standard dataset and provide a MWE that works?

Comment: @RKiselev: Please try again now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I cannot answer all your questions, but I'll try.

1) For the row numbers, you have to create a separate variable in your dataset, which contains labels for each data points. In this case, `mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)`. Then you use `geom_text` (see below).

2) For a smooth line representing a fit, use `geom_smooth`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = leverage, y = residuals.standard)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2* mean(mtcars$leverage), linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(data = influence, aes(x = leverage, y = residuals.standard), color = 'orange') +
  geom_smooth(se=F, span=0.6) +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(residuals.standard > 2, model, "")), cex=3, hjust=1.1)
```

3) Cook's distance cutoff line - I don't know what this line means. If you want to plot additional data, you can supply a second dataframe (let's say `cook_d` which has `x` and `y`) as the `data` argument of the corresponding geometry. You already did something similar in one of `geom_point`. This would look like this:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + ... + ... + 
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y), col="red", lty="dashed", data=cook_d)
```

Comment: Sorry, for some reason code blocks does note render as code blocks... I have no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: Code indent after numbered / bullet lists don't work so well. I've modified your numbered list slightly. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: The Cook's D is a statistic that reflects leverage and the residual to some degree. What I would want is a cutoff line that reflects e.g. cook's D of 0.7. Like in the provided plot by R this is a curve. Maybe someone else knows how to do that. I thought that assessing rownames would not require making a new column!! The smooth line I know how to make but that is not important here for me (you could not know that). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For `ggplot2` the data have to be in the [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) form, i.e. each variable in a single column, each observation in a single row. If you can calculate the cutoff line yourself separately and then add it to you dataframe, you can definitely plot it.